# Mapping a collection of foreign keys in nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have tables like this:

```
tblUsers
int UserID
string UserName


tblUsersInRoles
int UserID
int RoleID

tbleRoles
int RoleID
string RoleName
```

A user can be in many roles.

Is there a way to create my mapping file for my users so that my users object contains a list of Roles? I've figured out to do it so that I have a list of RoleID's like this:

```
<bag name="Roles" table="tblUsersInRoles" cascade="all">
  <key column="UserId"/>
  <one-to-many class="UsersInRoles"/>
</bag>
```

Is there a way to take that the next step via the mapping file and store the roles themselves instead of just their ID's?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need UsersInRoles, to do it you can use this mapping:

```
<bag name="Roles" table="tblUsersInRoles" cascade="none"> 
  <key column="UserId"></key> 
  <many-to-many class="Role" column="RoleId"></many-to-many> 
</bag>
```

And you can read [this post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2008/05/29/nhibernate-many-to-many-collections-or-mapping-is-not-one-table-one-class.aspx) about many to many. And about cascading - if you set cascade to all then deleting of user will couse deleting of his roles - I don't think you need it.